# How to change code depending on onPress state?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, react-props

I am using `react native` and `expo`.

I'd like to change height and add some `View`s when I click the box.
How to add some `View`s seems difficult for me.
So I've tried to change height on CSS first.

```js
const [style, setStyle] = useState(true);
```

I set 'style' as using `useState`.
Default value of style is 'true'.

```js
<Header onPress={() => setStyle(!style)}>
```

And I made it so that if I click Header box, `setStyle` changes into reversed value of style.

And on css code of box that I wanted to apply change, I use `props` to be changed depending of the style's state.

```js
height: ${(props) => (props.style ? "60px" : "260px")}
```

When I console.log the state value, it changes true to false and false to true correctly whenever I click the Header box.
But CSS style is not applied accordingly.
How can I make it applied?

And if you can teach me how to add some `View` more depending on the state, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included enough code to easily understand the structure of your app, or what exactly you're trying to do. Here's an example that should solve some of your issues... but you'll have to figure out how that fits your particular structure:

```js
function App() {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

    return <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setActive(!active)}>
            <Text>Press Me</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={{height: active ? 260 : 60}}>
            {active && <Text>Content</Text>}
        </View>
    </View>;
}
```

Comment: configuring useState and onPress is exactly the same.
But I use styled component in react native.

const Header = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  height: active? "60px": "260px"
`

so what i did was this above. But it doens't work.